# Converting a byte to a binary string in c#

Tags: c#, string, binary, byte

In c# I am converting a `byte` to `binary`, the actual answer is `00111111` but the result being given is `111111`. Now I really need to display even the 2 0s in front. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

I am using:

```
Convert.ToString(byteArray[20],2)
```

and the byte value is 63

Comment: similar, but in reverse: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/72176/using-c-what-is-the-most-efficient-method-of-converting-a-string-containing-bi

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Just change your code to:

```
string yourByteString = Convert.ToString(byteArray[20], 2).PadLeft(8, '0');
// produces "00111111"
```

Comment: this method will always make the string with 8 digits right? so if i will get a different value for instance 10001111 this will not add new 0s in front

Comment: @IanCian correct, no matter what there will always be 8 digits so if you supply them all, the `PadLeft` will do nothing but if you don't, it iwll fill in the left over space to the left with 0s.

Comment: You're right -- my suggestion wasn't right. I didn't test it.

Comment: @Iancian Did this end up solving your issue?

Comment: @Kelsey It does this because it knows that byte is always 8 in length when converting the byte to string?  Is that why it always works?

Comment: @johnny no, it first converts it to a string (using the `, 2)` simply says to convert it to binary), afterwards the padLeft says to add `0`s in front untill the string has a length of 8

Comment: I know it's not a normal use case, but why is it so much trouble to get the bits out of a struct that is defined as an array of 8-bits? This sounds like a piece of functionality that should be built into the byte struct. As well as this solution works, it's like asking someone for their name, and that person needing to look at their ID number so that they can then go to a registry to look up their own name.

Answer (score 32):

If I understand correctly, you have 20 values that you want to convert, so it's just a simple change of what you wrote.

To change single byte to 8 char string: `Convert.ToString( x, 2 ).PadLeft( 8, '0' )`

To change full array:

```
byte[] a = new byte[] { 1, 10, 100, 255, 200, 20, 2 };
string[] b = a.Select( x => Convert.ToString( x, 2 ).PadLeft( 8, '0' ) ).ToArray();
// Returns array:
// 00000010
// 00010100
// 11001000
// 11111111
// 01100100
// 00001010
// 00000001
```

To change your byte array to single string, with bytes separated with space:

```
byte[] a = new byte[] { 1, 10, 100, 255, 200, 20, 2 };
string s = string.Join( " ",
    a.Select( x => Convert.ToString( x, 2 ).PadLeft( 8, '0' ) ) );
// Returns: 00000001 00001010 01100100 11111111 11001000 00010100 00000010
```

if ordering of bytes is incorrect use [IEnumerable.Reverse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx):

```
byte[] a = new byte[] { 1, 10, 100, 255, 200, 20, 2 };
string s = string.Join( " ",
    a.Reverse().Select( x => Convert.ToString( x, 2 ).PadLeft( 8, '0' ) ) );
// Returns: 00000010 00010100 11001000 11111111 01100100 00001010 00000001
```

Answer (score 4):

```
public static string ByteArrayToString(byte[] ba)
{
    StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder(ba.Length * 2);
    foreach (byte b in ba)
        hex.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b);
    return hex.ToString();
}
```

Comment: This code gives output like this:
55  4d  04  a8  4f  2a  cd  01  40  00  81  57  4d  32  36  30  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  02  0f  00  00  00  00  00  00  02  0f  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  06  a5

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
public static String convert(byte b)
{
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(8);
            int[] bl  = new int[8];

    for (int i = 0; i < bl.Length; i++)
    {               
        bl[bl.Length - 1 - i] = ((b & (1 << i)) != 0) ? 1 : 0;
    }

    foreach ( int num in bl) str.Append(num);

    return str.ToString();
}
```