# Show binary code of external files/program

Tags: c#, .net, binary

One way or another, all digital data is stored in 0 and 1. That's the principle of binary data, I guess.

Is there a method or package that can show you the binary code of a file/single-exe-program of how it is actually being stored in the 0/1 format??

I would see it like:
- import a certain, random file
- convert it to it's 0/1 format
- store the the 1/0-data in a txt (streamwriter/binarywriter)

if yes, is this available in any .NET language (pref: c#)?

Comment: What you see when you open a binary files in something like note pad is the set of characters that represent the binary octets. Look up an ASCII table to understand what I mean. Converting that representation to actual 0 and 1 characters effectively multiplies the file size by 8 (best case scenario) as each character you see is now an octet representing a simple bit. Hope you understand the "principle" you mentioned on your question now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially you just need to break this into two steps:

1. Convert a file into bytes
2. Convert a byte into a binary string

[The first step is easy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes.aspx):

```
var fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(someFileName);
```

The second step is less straightforward, [but still pretty easy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3581798/328193):

```
var byteString = string.Concat(fileBytes.Select(x => Convert.ToString(x, 2).PadLeft(8, '0')))
```

The idea here is that you select each byte individually, converting each one to a binary string (pad left so each one is 8 characters, since many bytes have leading zeroes), and concatenate all of those into a single string.  (Courtesy in part of @xanatos' comment below.)

Comment: The second line is wrong I think... `string.Concat(fileBytes.Select(x => Convert.ToString(x, 2).PadLeft(8, '0')))`

Comment: @xanatos: Could be.  I'm curious enough that I'm currently firing up VS to test :)

Comment: @xanatos: You are indeed correct, I'll update the answer.  Thanks!

Comment: make it a stream so if the file is big it wont cause memory issue :-)

Comment: @Fredou: Ok, now it's just getting silly :)  You're right, there could easily be memory problems with very large files.  *Most* files aren't that large.  Though to be fair both the input *and* the output would need to be streams in that case, since holding a string which is technically *eight times larger* than the file wouldn't be good for memory either :)

Comment: i made the streaming answer :-)

Comment: @Fredou: Good answer:)  Let's add further silliness... What if this logic is buried in the business layer and has no knowledge of or responsibility to the physical input and output of the application?  It needs to expose abstract/generic streams, but not act upon them.  And... go!  :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer @David. It helped me out. I surrounded it with a filestream and binarywriter. Now i have a nice txt-file with 0 and 1's :-)

Comment: I will do it if i remember this weekend ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is something what you are looking for:

```
byte [] contents = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for(int i = 0; i<contents .Length; i++)
{
  builder.Append( Convert.ToString(contents[i], 2).PadLeft(8, '0') );
}
```

Now, you can for example write `builder` contents to a text file.

Comment: Please, use a `StringBuilder`... The world doesn't need another [Schlemiel the Painter's Algorithm](http://en.wikichip.org/wiki/Schlemiel_the_Painter's_Algorithm)

Comment: @xanatos: ok changed that

Answer (score 1):

this will stream the conversion, useful if you have huge file.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var buffer = new byte[1024];
            int pos = 0; 

            using (var fileIn = new FileStream(@"c:\test.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            using (var fileOut = new FileStream(@"c:\test.txt.binary", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
                while((pos = fileIn.Read(buffer,0,buffer.Length)) > 0)
                    foreach (var value in buffer.Take(pos).Select(x => Convert.ToString(x, 2).PadLeft(8, '0')))
                        fileOut.Write(value.Select(x => (byte)x).ToArray(), 0, 8);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can open the file in binary mode. Didn't test it but it should work :

```
BitArray GetBits(string fuleSrc)
{
     byte[] bytesFile;
     using (FileStream file = new FileStream(fuleSrc, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
     {
          bytesFile = new byte[file.Length];
          file.Read(bytes, 0, (int)file.Length);
     }

     return new BitArray(bytesFile);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution using `FileStream`, `StreamWriter`, `StringBuilder` and `Convert`

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(InputFILEPATH, FileMode.Open))
    {
          while (fs.Position != fs.Length)
          {
              sb.Append(Convert.ToString(fs.ReadByte(),2));
          }
    }
    using (StreamWriter stw = new StreamWriter(File.Open(OutputFILEPATH,FileMode.OpenOrCreate)))
    {
            stw.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
    }
   Console.ReadKey();
}
```