# c# converting char to list of booleans

Tags: c#, type-conversion

I need to convert char into bits and add it into `myBuffer` type of `list<bool>`.

```
List<bool> myBuffer = ...
char symbol = 'A';

myBuffer.Add(...symbol...);
```

Is there some easy way?

Comment: I am doing huffman compression and need to convert char on "bits". In my case im using list of booleans to represent bit stream and after reaching some point of number of bits i convert them into bytes.

Comment: By bits i mean elements of my boolean list

Comment: There is a BitArray class. Use that instead of List of bool, that will help you to achieve what you want

Comment: Is this efficient if i have program which every cicle wants to add something into BitArray?

Comment: Converting char to bit array is strange thing to do to start with, so discussing if one approach is better in some abstract way (rather than some concreete requirement like code size, execution time, code style/1337-ness) is hard. Adding some context why this is even practical could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the binary string ([this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3581798/3768871)) and then apply `select` function to get a list of Boolean:

```
var result = Convert.ToString((byte)symbole, 2).PadLeft(8, '0').Select(bit => bit == '1').ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this solution too complicated? If symbol would be a single character of string

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
char symbol = "A";
foreach (byte b in Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(symbol.ToString()))
{
     sb.Append(Convert.ToString(b, 2));
}
string bits = sb.ToString();
List<bool> myBuffer= ...

for (int i = 0; i < bits .Length; i++)
{
     if (bits [i] == '0')
     {
          myBuffer.Add(false);
     }
     else if (bits [i] == '1')
     {
         myBuffer.Add(true);
     }
}
```

Comment: Is it answer (code looks plausible, also original question is about char and code starts with string, but it sort  of does not matter)? Did you plan to post it as edit to your question? If it is intended to be an answer - make sure to [edit] test to be positive statement and not a question, otherwise delete and [edit] question itself.