# How to make a 4 bit binary to 8bit binary number?

Tags: c#, binary, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I am using C#
I have a variable `byte a=0b00001111`. 
When i print it on console it shows as truncated value: `1111`
I want to print it right as it is: `00001111`

I want a **GENERALIZED** method or code snippet which does the exact same thing which I want. 
I tried ANDing it with `11111111` but still the same answer.

Please help.

Comment: `.ToString("00000000")` ?

Comment: what mechanism are you currently using to get the bitwise version?

Comment: @MattBeldon that will do integer representation, not bitwise; the output will be `00000015`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting a byte to a binary string in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3581674/converting-a-byte-to-a-binary-string-in-c-sharp)

Comment: "I want to print it right as it is" - it already is; `byte a=0b00001111` is **exactly the same as** `byte a=0b1111` - which is **exactly the same as** `byte a = 15` - which is **exactly the same as** `byte a = 00015`. Numbers don't include formatting, so it has no way of knowing that you had leading zeros in your code. Likewise, `a` *never was* a 4 bit binary number - it was always *at least* 8 bits - and could actually be 32 bits throughout, when executed (during execution, values are width-promoted; they only exist in their short form *when stored*)

Comment: @MarcGravell cheers for info :)

Answer (score 7):

Presumably just left-pad?

```
    byte a = 0b00001111;
    var s = Convert.ToString(a, 2).PadLeft(8, '0');
    Console.WriteLine(s);
```