# c# convert any type to string in the form of binary or to an array of integer

Tags: c#

every data on computer is 0 and 1 , even though the data represent something else , but at the smallest scale it is 0 and 1 . How do i convert any type to binary string ? or to an array of integer with each integer value is either 1 or 0 and nothing else .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3581674/converting-a-byte-to-a-binary-string-in-c-sharp Take a look here

Comment: what have you ***tried yourself*** so far? what problems did you encounter? what have you researched?

Comment: The general problem isn't solvable in .NET, because in .NET you can't read directly the memory of objects. You can read the memory rappresentation of primitive types, string and some other types, but you can't take a look at the inner workings of `new int[5]`

Comment: If you could achieve this, what would it help you *do*? If you're looking for *serialization*, that's the word to search on and you need to consider what relationship there is between the serializer and deserializer (in terms of how separate they are in terms of process/machine boundaries and temporally)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever No i am not looking for serialization , im looking specific just to the answer to this problem .And what help it would do to me ? a lot , it just takes too long to explain here so lets just assume it is my secret.

Comment: Well then, good news. Every value of every type, in fact, maps to the string of digits `100101`. There. It's a good job that the purpose of doing this is irrelevant to answering, it makes producing an answer much easier.

Answer (score 1):

The general problem isn't solvable in C#, because in C# you can't read directly the memory of reference types (and you can't even read the memory of a reference to see where it is "pointing" to).

What you can read is the memory rappresentation of primitive types (that is `Boolean`, `Byte`, `SByte`, `Int16`, `UInt16`, `Int32`, `UInt32`, `Int64`, `UInt64`, `IntPtr`, `UIntPtr`, `Char`, `Double`, and `Single`) but as I've said you can't really "take a look" at reference types. You can't "see" the hidden fields of a `String` or of an `int[]` for example, and it can be complex even to read the memory of complex value types (`struct`).

For the primitive types I listed (excluding `IntPtr` and `UIntPr`) you can

```
double value = 5;
string str = string.Join(" ", BitConverter.GetBytes(value).Select(x => Convert.ToString(x, 2).PadLeft(8, '0')));
```

For `IntPtr` and `UIntPtr` you must first downcast them to `Int32`/`UInt32` if your process is 32 bits or `Int64`/`UInt64` if it is 64 bits.

As a sidenote, it isn't entirely clear for me in which order should the bits of a byte be printed. I've read that "normally", on little endian systems (your PC with Intel processor), the bit order is the same as the byte order. I'm not calculating this in the code, so `(int)1` on an Intel is

```
00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

So I'm printing bits in a byte in big endian order, and I'm printing bytes of value types in their memory rappresentation (on Intel normally little endian)

Comment: `unsafe`? Obviously it's unsafe but in current implementations a managed ref is not a black box. I understand that is somewhat irrelevant to the general point