# displayin message on binary format c#

Tags: binary

hey guys i recently created a c# winform program by using serial port. Im sending and receving data using user textbox and i wanna display "receiving messages" in **binary format**. I created an array and i think i need to pull from array one by one but im not sure. Here is my unfinished code, can somebody help me figure out.

```
namespace serialchannel

{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        foreach (String s in System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames())
        {
            portNames.Items.Add(s);
        }
    }

    public System.IO.Ports.SerialPort sport;

    private void ConnectButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        String port = portNames.Text;
        int baudrate = Convert.ToInt32(baudRates.Text);
        Parity parity = (Parity)Enum.Parse(typeof(Parity), parityType.Text);

        SerialPortConnect(port, baudrate, parity);

    }
    public void SerialPortConnect(String port, int baudrate, Parity parity)
    {
        sport = new System.IO.Ports.SerialPort(port, baudrate);
        try
        {
            sport.Open();

            sport.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(SportDataReceived);
            if (sport.IsOpen)
            {
                signal.Visible = true;
                signal.Text = "connection successful";
                signal.ForeColor = Color.Green;
            }
            else
            {
                signal.Visible = true;
                signal.Text = "connection err";
                signal.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine("err", ex); }           
    }
    private void SportDataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        displayedTextBox.AppendText( "received:"+ sport.ReadExisting()+ "\n");
    }

    private void SendButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        String data = userInputTextBox.Text;
        sport.Write(data);
        **byte []arr = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);**


        
        displayedTextBox.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + "sent:" + data);
    }
    
    private void CloseButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (sport.IsOpen)
        {
            sport.Close();
            displayedTextBox.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + "disconnected");
        }
    }

    private void baudRates_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there.  It is hard to tell what you want to do, from the way your question is phrased.  Do you want to display the text `Receiving Data`, as in that specific text, but in binary?   Or did you want to take the line that has the two asterisks on either side and convert that data to binary?  I will assume the latter.

By the "line surrounded by double asterisks," I specifically mean your code

```
byte []arr = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
```

As we know, binary is 0s and 1s. Each zero and each one is a bit, and each element of the array `arr` is a byte, which is always 8 bits long (at least, in the ASCII encoding, it is).  Binary is what is known as a [base-2 number system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number).

Per the question asked and answered [over here on another Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3581674/converting-a-byte-to-a-binary-string-in-c-sharp), for each individual byte in your array, `arr`, you can represent it in binary via the following:

```
string yourByteString = Convert.ToString(byteArray[20], 2).PadLeft(8, '0');
```

As per the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tostring?view=net-6.0#system-convert-tostring(system-byte-system-int32)), the specific overload of `ToString` used is one that takes the current element of the `byteArray`, and represents it as a string in Base 2 which is binary.

The `PadLeft` method then pads it on then left with zeros in case the byte you are converting cannot be represented with 8 binary digits.

Let's create a new class in our project, say `ByteToBinaryConverter` and let's make it a `static` class.  Furthermore, let's make our conversion method an extension method of `byte`, so that we can use it in a fluent (easy-to-read code) manner:

```
namespace serialchannel
{
    public static class ByteToBinaryConverter
    {
        public static string ToBinaryString(this byte byteToConvert)
        {
            return Convert.ToString(byteToConvert, 2).PadLeft(8, '0');
        }
    }
}
```

Now, let's use the method in your `SendButton_Click` event handler method.  I am going to repeat the code of that method here, with `/* ... */` meaning ignore everything else, and calling our new method:

```
namespace serialchannel
{
    public static class ByteToBinaryConverter
    {
        public static string ToBinaryString(this byte byteToConvert)
        {
            return Convert.ToString(byteToConvert, 2).PadLeft(8, '0');
        }
    }

    public class Form1 : Form
    {
        /* ... rest of class ... */
        
        private void SendButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var data = userInputTextBox.Text;
            sport.Write(data);
            
            var arr = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
            
            var textToBeDisplayed = "";
            foreach(var element in arr)
            {
                textToBeDisplayed += element.ToBinaryString();
            }
            
            displayedTextBox.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + "sent: " + textToBeDisplayed);
        }
        
        /* ... rest of class ... */

    }
}
```

Notice the use of the `var` keyword instead of explicit data types.  This makes use of [Local variable type inference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_syntax#Local_variable_type_inference) features of C# 3.0.  Using the `var` keyword saves you from having to use explicit types in your code for variables.  The C# compiler can figure it out based on what data you are initializing the variable with.

If you want to use explicit types, then I suggest the following variation of the code:

```
namespace serialchannel
{
    public static class ByteToBinaryConverter
    {
        public static string ToBinaryString(this byte byteToConvert)
        {
            return Convert.ToString(byteToConvert, 2).PadLeft(8, '0');
        }
    }
    
    public class Form1 : Form
    {
        /* ... rest of class ... */
        
        private void SendButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string data = userInputTextBox.Text;
            sport.Write(data);
            
            byte[] arr = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
            
            string textToBeDisplayed = "";
            foreach(byte element in arr)
            {
                textToBeDisplayed += element.ToBinaryString();
            }
            
            displayedTextBox.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + "sent: " + textToBeDisplayed);
        }
        
        /* ... rest of class ... */

    }
}
```

Above, I am using all lowercase versions of the type names; i.e., I am saying `string` not `String` as you have it.  There really is no appreciable difference but it looks cleaner this way, in my opinion.